# Rspec no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm getting the following error with rspec:

```
1) LandingController landing#index returns http success
 Failure/Error: get :index
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"landing"}
 # ./spec/controllers/landing_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LandingController do

  describe "landing#index" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

I mounted it as `root :to => 'landing#index'`. All other tests are passing, only this one is failing, can someone help me to understand why?

For completeness this is the output from `rake routes`

```
root                         /                                      landing#index
auth_google_oauth2_callback  /auth/google_oauth2/callback(.:format) sessions#create
                    signout  /signout(.:format)                     sessions#destroy
                  dashboard  /dashboard(.:format)                   dashboard#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spork you may need to restart the server if you updated routes.

Answer (score -1):

did you try to access the root page with `get '/'`? should work.

Comment: Yes, I tried. And it fails with `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"landing", :action=>"/"}`
`